# how to convert a as string in a file saved array to an array object in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I saved two 2-dimensional lists into a file by python, now i want to recover this string to two lists but have no idea how to do this well without a lot of messy splitting. Is there any function for this problem?

File (lists.txt) looks like this:

```
[['someting1', 'someting2', 'someting3', 'someting4'], ['someting else1', 'someting else2', 'someting else3', 'someting else4']]
[['different1', 'different2', 'different3'], ['wow is this different1', 'wow is this different2', 'wow is this different3']]
```

This should be converted in two 2-dimensional list where results could look like this

```
print(listForLine1[1][1]) >> 'someting else2'
print(listForLine1[0][2]) >> 'different3'
```

Thanks
vimu

Edit:

I found that saving the lists as text is no good idea because of special characters like ' and " which can cause complications with converting this text back to a list again.

A better solution for this is using a pandas dataframe an saving this to a csv which can later be reopened with pandas.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

dataToAdd = [["test","test"]["test","test"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataToAdd)
file = open("filetowriteto", 'w+')
file.write(df.to_csv())
```

Comment: How did you save it and why; do you perhaps still search for a better (reloadable) way to save it?

Comment: sure if you have some idea let me know i scraped some data from a site and had to save them in any way but dont wanted to use a db at this point

Comment: The most important thing from my point of view would be: which is the structure which holds your data after scraping/before saving? A 2D-numpy-array? A list of lists? A dict of lists?...

Comment: it was a list of lists

Comment: As your list of lists is not regular (each list contains lists of same lengths) the proposed json solution seems the best to me. I just wondered because of the term `2D-array` and your numpy tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
json.load(file_obj)
```

or

```
json.loads(str_obj)
```

For that, you will have to import JSON using

```
import json
```

Keep in mind you use double inverted commas (") rather than single (') while writing the text in the file.

This will load the string from the file as a dictionary/list object.
Hope this helps.
Welcome to Stack Overflow!  :)

Comment: thanks a lot =) first had some error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2) but after you added the hint with the quotes it worked great

Comment: do you have some other conclusion the refomatting of my data seems messy because in the text fields sometimes commas are used so the json.loads drops some JSONDecodeError

Comment: @vimu can you be more clear and give me the exact text which returns JSONDecode Error. Also, please refer to [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON and find out what is causing the DecodeError.

Comment: thank you for the offer but i changed my code to use a panda dataframe so it's working fine now =)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [734]: alist1 = [['someting1', 'someting2', 'someting3', 'someting4'], ['someting else1', 'someting else2', 'someting else3', 'someting else4']]   
In [735]: str(alist1)                                                           
Out[735]: "[['someting1', 'someting2', 'someting3', 'someting4'], ['someting else1', 'someting else2', 'someting else3', 'someting else4']]"
```

A list like that can be saved as a `csv` using `savetxt`:

```
In [736]: np.savetxt('strings.txt',alist1, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')             

In [737]: cat strings.txt                                                       
someting1,someting2,someting3,someting4
someting else1,someting else2,someting else3,someting else4
```

I could have specified the format field width to line up the columns.

Also choose a delimiter that does not appear in the texts.

In any case this file can be loaded with `genfromtxt`.  (pandas csv reader would also work).

```
In [738]: np.genfromtxt('strings.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=str)                
Out[738]: 
array([['someting1', 'someting2', 'someting3', 'someting4'],
       ['someting else1', 'someting else2', 'someting else3',
        'someting else4']], dtype='<U14')
```

Generally writing and reading lists or `ndarray` with their `str` format is not a good idea. Parsing can be harder, and even impossible.  That format is intended for human readability, not machine parsing.

As demonstrated by the other answer, `json` is a good choice for lists (and dictionaries).